# Clickhouse java client multiple threads select perfomance

Tags: java, multithreading, clickhouse

```
try (ClickHouseClient client = ClickHouseClient.newInstance(ClickHouseProtocol.HTTP)) {
            ClickHouseResponse response = client.connect(getServer())// or client.connect(endpoints)
                    .format(ClickHouseFormat.RowBinaryWithNamesAndTypes)
                    .query(selectQuery)
                    .executeAndWait();
            {
                return castResult(response);
            }
        }
```

I am using kafka with 100 partition or 100 threads that means that I execute the select query till 100 times in the same time maximum.
When I try with 1 threads, the performance is less than 100 ms while when I am using with multiple threads the performance is around 1500ms. In the code there is no other complicated query.
When I tried the perfomance with a script of curl from bash, the perfomance was still good less 200ms.
What it is the best way to achieve great perfomance with java and clickhouse and multiple threads?
Also I do a insert like one in 30 seconds for 200-300 elements

Comment: There is only one database server, only one network, and only one disk. You can multithread all you like at the client, but, as you’ve just proven, you will only make it worse.

Comment: @user207421 ok but how can I solve this issue? and why with bash script the perfomance is better?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the origin of your data (see "In transactionally consistent caches" or "In transactionally inconsistent caches"), you may consider using the **use_query_cache** setting, for example:

```
SELECT some_expensive_calculation(column_1, column_2)
FROM table
SETTINGS use_query_cache = true;
```

here you will find all the details: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/query-cache.

Reducing latency and resource consumption could further increase performance